# Need just time from this date time format

Tags: javascript, date, time

I was looking for EDT time and got this in this format :

```
Wed Nov 01 2017 06:42:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Although, I just want it like 6:42 AM to display !! I tried date time function 
but doesnt help !!
```

Is it advisable to do this with any string function or will it give issue in future (I dont want any calculation on this )

Answer (score 2):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to work with date in JS.

```
moment("Wed Nov 01 2017 06:42:26 GMT+0530").format("hh:mm a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var date = "Wed Nov 01 2017 06:42:26 GMT+0530";
var formattedDate = new Date(date);

var hours = formattedDate.getHours();
var minutes = formattedDate.getMinutes();

hours = (hours > 12) ? (hours - 12) : hours;
var period = (hours > 12) ? 'PM' : 'AM';

var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + period;
```

or you can also use moment.js, [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) is the details on 'format' function.

```
var time = moment(date).format("hh:mm A");
```

Comment: For 00:30 this will return 00:30 AM instead of 12:30 AM. Consider: `hours = hours % 12 || 12`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var date = new Date(); 

var hour = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();

var time = hour + ':' + minutes;
```

This would work.

Note: momentjs is great library for time manipulation, it is not good idea to include such a big library for small functions like this.

Comment: I agree with you but to get AM/PM format with vanilla JS is little more complex.

Comment: The question was to get time in hours format. `var format = hour > 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';` will give AM/PM format. But moment.js is really good suggestion.